# How to set a .env file path in Nuxt config?

Tags: nuxt.js, config, filepath, dotenv

I'm migrating to Nuxt new runtime config from the [@nuxtjs/dotenv](https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module) module. I tried to follow the [official guidelines](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/moving-from-nuxtjs-dotenv-to-runtime-config#migrating-to-the-nuxtjs-runtime-config-from-the-env-property), but I couldn't find a way to specify the path to my env files and my default .env file isn't loaded at build time.

Is there a way to set a .env file path in nuxt.config.js without using @nuxtjs/dotenv ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Facing this issue trying to use different .env files per environment

Comment: @JonathanRobbins hi, mind looking at my answer?

Comment: @kissu I'll give it a try. I ended up taking a different route. One .env file containing tokens that are replaced when deployed to an environment

Answer (score 0):

I've just noticed this question. Do you mind trying this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68338032/8816585?

Mostly specifying the path like this

```
yarn dev --dotenv variables/.env_file
```

---

Otherwise, this is also a solution (even if it's using dotenv...): https://stackoverflow.com/a/67987659/8816585

```js
buildModules: ["@nuxtjs/fontawesome", ['@nuxtjs/dotenv', { path: './' }]],
```