# How to set custom path for dotenv in nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, environment-variables, nuxt.js, dotenv

I have the following `nuxt.config.js`, where in the `srcDir` is pointing to "main-app" and I have placed the .env outside of it. So in the `nuxt.config.js`, how can set the custom path in line 1

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: '../.env' })
```

such that my process.env works
[image]

Also the buildModules in nuxt.config.js is as follows

```
buildModules: ["@nuxtjs/fontawesome", "@nuxtjs/dotenv"],
```

Comment: You should not post code as images. Rather, copy pasta it as text here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I need to set the live path of the env in the buildModules section just like follows

```
 buildModules: ["@nuxtjs/fontawesome", ['@nuxtjs/dotenv', { path: './' }]],
```

Answer (score 4):

**If you are using version > 2.13 then you won't need to install dotenv anymore because it's already built in**
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/nuxt-config/#runtimeconfig

> .env support
> Similar to vue-cli (*), .env file will be always loaded via dotenv and is accessible via process.env and options._env. process.env is updated so one can use it right inside nuxt.config for runtime config. Values are interpolated and expanded with an improved version of dotenv-expand. .env file is also watched to reload during nuxt dev. Path can be set via cli --dotenv  or disabled by --dotenv false.

**I created the .env.xxx files and created the corresponding scripts**

[image: file .env]

[image: file package.json]

Comment: Thank you for this, I lost few days and gave up, but found this and tried again, now working flawless

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried this?

```js
const { resolve } = require('path')
require('dotenv').config({ path: resolve(__dirname,"../.env") })
```

Taken from [this answer](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/116#issuecomment-575891178).

---

Otherwise, it looks like there are a lot of solution on this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42335383/8816585

---

EDIT:
you could write this at the top of your `nuxt.config.js` file, outside of the `export default`'s scope.

```js
const { resolve } = require('path')
const current = resolve(__dirname)
const upper = resolve(__dirname, '..')
console.log('current', current)
console.log('upper', upper)

const testFolder = '../'

fs.readdir(testFolder, (_err, files) => {
  files.forEach((file) => {
    console.log(file)
  })
})

export default {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
  // rest of the nuxt.config.js file below
```

Giving this on my Linux machine.
[image]

Comment: I used      require('dotenv').config({path: resolve(__dirname,"../.env")})

Comment: You should console.log the directory above to see if you do find the `.env` in it, and of course double-check that this is fine so far (that you're not one level above/deeper).

Comment: Actually putting console.log in nuxt.config.js is not showing up

Comment: any other way to check?

Comment: It should work. Google a way to find out how to print the content of the `__dirname` directory. Maybe this is a windows only issue?

Comment: mine is also linux only..let me check the edited answer

Comment: I am trying to see the console.log in the browser...is that wrong?

Comment: Should I seperately run the nuxt.config.js file then?

Comment: This is backend code that you can only run on a `Node.js` environment. So, you need to write it on the "server". Edited my question again. But it's pretty much in the `nuxt.config.js` file, before the actual configuration. Or you can also make it in any `.js` file and call `node myFile.js` on it.

Comment: finally I was able to figure out 
Actually I was not setting the live path of the env file in the build modules
The right path is defined as

 buildModules: ["@nuxtjs/fontawesome", ['@nuxtjs/dotenv', { path: './' }]],