# How to specify another directory or name for the .env file in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I don't want to follow the convention of putting my environment variable (`.env` file) at the root directory of my Nuxt project.

How can I achieve another directory or even name for it without using the [@nuxtjs/dotenv](https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module) module? (I know this one is already baked into Nuxt since `v2.13` and hence, not needed anymore).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at this answer: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/8331#issuecomment-727533175

You can specify a different **location** and **name** if you'd like, with the following

```
yarn dev --dotenv variables/.env_file
```

With the following structure

[image]

Of course, this will work with `yarn generate` and `yarn build`.

Comment: ok, so it must be defined on each build and there is no way to define the path in `nuxt.config.js`. thanks

Comment: @MojtabaBarari IMO, this makes more sense to have it on the build command. Either keep it in the source directory, or if you want to override it, do it on the build yep.

Answer (score 1):

I got no luck with the `--dotenv` flag, so I'm just using replacing .env with the desired contents upon build or serve, like `cp .env.xxx .env && yarn dev`.
Not the prettiest, but good enough.

In your case the command would be `cp variables/.env_file .env && yarn dev`.