# Nuxt recognizes variables in .env file, but can't see them if I use .env.local instead (which I want to be ignored)

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, nuxt.js

My `.env` (or `.env.local`):

```bash
apiURL=https://<dev-url>
```

My `nuxt.config.js`

```js
publicRuntimeConfig: {
  apiURL: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? 'https://<prod-url>'
    : process.env.apiURL
},
proxy: {
  '/api_vue': {
    target: process.env.apiURL,
    changeOrigin: true
  }
},
```

Everything works well until I add `.local` to `.env`.
Nuxt says:

> Error: [HPM] Missing "target" option. Example: {target:   │
> nuxt-app    |    │   "http://www.example.org"}

Comment: Can you try that one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68338032/8816585 Also, do you only want to have a `.local.env`? Isn't it supposed to be `.env.local` (local should be a suffix AFAIK)? Also, what happens if you have a combo of: `.env` + `.env.local`? I'm not even sure that this is recommended anyway: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#should-i-have-multiple-env-files

Answer (score 0):

You should import [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) to load `.env` variables.

```js
require("dotenv").config()
```

I also recommend to rename your `.env` variables to the following format:

```
apiURL --> API_URL
```